# Difference between base64 and charset utf-8

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, base64

When reading a file in binary, I did recognize that,

- if its a text base file, I have to use data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,
- and if its multimedia file, I have to use data:image/png;base64,

I did try to use base64 and when I try to download a file using following syntax, it gives me an error.

```
<a href="data:text/plain;base64,VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA%3D%1E" download="sample text.txt">download</a>
```

The script that generates above code is

```
<script>
var filecontent = binaryAgent("010101100100011101010110011110100110010001000011010000100100010101100010001100100100111000110001011000100101011101010110011101010110010001000001001111010011110");
download("sample text.txt", filecontent, "data:text/plain;base64,");
function binaryAgent(str) {
          // Removes the spaces from the binary string
          str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
          // Pretty (correct) print binary (add a space every 8 characters)
          str = str.match(/.{1,8}/g).join(" ");

          var binString = '';

          str.split(' ').map(function(bin) {
              binString += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2));
          });

          return binString;
        }

        function download(filename, text, encodedType) {
          var element = document.createElement('a');
          element.setAttribute('href', encodedType + encodeURIComponent(text));
          element.setAttribute('download', filename);

          element.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(element);

          element.click();

          document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
</script>
```

What is the difference between these two types? Can't I use base64 even for text based files?

Comment: Well, is the text file also base 64 encoded? What's the error?

Comment: when I click download, it says 'Failed - Network Error'. You can run it and see. This should download a text document containing 'Test Document'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just generated wrong base64, replace the

```
data:text/plain;base64,VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA%3D%1E
```

with

```
data:text/plain;base64,VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA
```

Comment: This works. But the content of the file generates dynamically. How can I solve it?

Comment: You probably have some padding or encoding problem, can you post the line of code that prints the tag

Comment: I did add the original code to the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your binary string's length is not a multiple of 8, you are missing the last bit